# Workaround: site is www.example.com code incl. document.domain='example.com'

Tags: facebook

A customer site that I cannot change has the line `document.domain = "example.com"` while the site is at `www.example.com`.

The effect is that FaceBook Connect window login gets stuck after submitting username+password.

Firebug shows its in infinite loop inside dispatchmessage function, which gives perpetual exception:

```
Error: Permission denied for <http://www.example.com> to get property Window.FB from <http://example.com>
```

Any idea how to work around this? I prefer not to ask the customer to remove the `document.domain='example.com'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a really bad idea to tell the visitor's browser that the website is being served from a particular domain, when it in fact is not. The best solution would be to change that line. I take it you don't want to change it because they have some client-side code that depends on this?

One workaround would be to change the Facebook application's Connect URL to `http://example.com`, since Facebook's JavaScript will think that is where it is being executed.